# Trying to change my mac wallpaper but the background won't update

Tags: python, macos, wallpaper

I made a program that is meant to get image urls from unsplash.com, turns a random one into a jpeg file and then updates my mac wallpaper to be the chosen image.

Here's the code:

```
# from appscript import app, mactypes
import os
import subprocess
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import random

image_urls = []
queries = ["/mac", "/macbook", ""]
SCRIPT = """/usr/bin/osascript<<END
tell application "System Events" to set picture of (reference to current desktop) to "%s"
END"""


def get_image_urls(website_url, photo_url_start):
    response = requests.get(website_url).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")

    images = soup.find_all("img")
    for image in images:
        src = image["src"]
        if photo_url_start in src:
            if not src in image_urls:
                image_urls.append(src)


for query in queries:
    get_image_urls(website_url=f"https://unsplash.com/wallpapers/desktop{query}",
                   photo_url_start="https://images.unsplash.com/photo")

img_data = requests.get(random.choice(image_urls)).content
with open('wallpaper_background.jpeg', 'wb') as handler:
    handler.write(img_data)

abspath = os.path.abspath("wallpaper_background.jpeg")
subprocess.Popen(SCRIPT % abspath, shell=True)

# app('Finder').desktop_picture.set(mactypes.File("wallpaper_background.jpeg"))
```

The jpeg file is created and shown to be the current wallpaper in system settings, however, it won't actually show up for me. I commented out the previous attempt I made.
If anyone knows how I can actually make my wallpaper change I would really appreciate it.